# Не выпадает меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сделал я менюшку. Почему-то при клике оно не выпадет. Это адаптивное меню при разрешении 768px основное прячется и появляется кнопка меню, но оно у меня не выпадает =(

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.main_mnu ul li').slideToggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle
  
  $(window).resize(function() {  
  if (  $(window).width() > 768 ) {   
   $('.main_mnu ul li').removeAttr('style');
   }
 });//end resize
});//end ready
```

```css
.top_line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #3A3D40;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4A4D50;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.main_mnu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
 
}
.main_mnu li  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  
}
.main_mnu li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  
  background-image: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1608/2b/4dc09f3ee992.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main_mnu li:last-of-type:after {
   content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background-image: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1608/2b/4dc09f3ee992.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.main_mnu li:hover {
  background-color: #35373A;
}
.main_mnu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
.main_mnu a:hover {
  color: #7A9CB2;
}

.menu-trigger{
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 25px;
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .main_mnu ul{
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .main_mnu li {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3A3D40;
    border-top: 1px solid #2d2f32;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
 .menu-trigger {
    display: block;
  }
  
 .main_mnu ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top_line">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="main_mnu">
            
       <ul>
                <a href="#" class="menu-trigger">Menu</a>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Potrfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul> 
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заработало, осталось только jQuery подключить:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Проверьте:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.main_mnu ul li').slideToggle(500);
  });//end slide toggle
  
  $(window).resize(function() {  
  if (  $(window).width() > 768 ) {   
   $('.main_mnu ul li').removeAttr('style');
   }
 });//end resize
});//end ready
```

```css
.top_line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #3A3D40;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4A4D50;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.main_mnu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
 
}
.main_mnu li  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  
}
.main_mnu li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  
  background-image: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1608/2b/4dc09f3ee992.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main_mnu li:last-of-type:after {
   content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background-image: url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1608/2b/4dc09f3ee992.png);
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.main_mnu li:hover {
  background-color: #35373A;
}
.main_mnu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
.main_mnu a:hover {
  color: #7A9CB2;
}

.menu-trigger{
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 25px;
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .main_mnu ul{
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .main_mnu li {
    display: block;
    background-color: #3A3D40;
    border-top: 1px solid #2d2f32;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
 .menu-trigger {
    display: block;
  }
  
 .main_mnu ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top_line">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="main_mnu">
            
       <ul>
                <a href="#" class="menu-trigger">Menu</a>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Potrfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul> 
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```